# Usar Stack en java para restringuir cadena

Tags: java

[()()] → equilibrado
[()(]) → no equilibrado
[(()()] → no equilibrado
[()[()]] → equilibrado

Estoy utilizando esta cadena

```
String cadena="[()(]) "
```

System.out.println(verificaParentesis(cadena));
Esta mal digamos
deberia dar false pero a la hora de realizar la funcion me imprime true

adjunto codigo:

```
 private static boolean verificaParentesis(String cadena) {

    Stack<String> pila=new Stack<String>();
    int i=0;
    while (i<cadena.length()){

   if (cadena.charAt(i)=='('){ //Si tenemos un paréntesis de apertura, lo apilamos
   if (cadena.charAt(i)==('[')) {
       pila.add("[");
   }else{
            pila.add("(");
   }
        }else if (cadena.charAt(i)==')'){
            if (cadena.charAt(i)==']') {
        if (!pila.empty()){ // Si la pila no está vacía, sacamos un paréntesis de apertura
                pila.pop();
            }else {    // Si la pila está vacía, los paréntesis no están equilibrados
                pila.add("]");
                break;
            }
   }else{
            if (!pila.empty()){ // Si la pila no está vacía, sacamos un paréntesis de apertura
                pila.pop();
            }else {    // Si la pila está vacía, los paréntesis no están equilibrados
                pila.add(")");
                break;
            }

        }

        }


        i++;
    }

    return pila.empty();
}
```

Comment: Probaste organizando tu codigo? si el primer caracter es [ que pasa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes muchos `if`s anidados y algunos de ellos con condiciones que nunca se cumplirán, por ejemplo:

```
if (cadena.charAt(i)=='('){
    if (cadena.charAt(i)==('[')) {
        pila.add("[");
    }else{
        pila.add("(");
    }
}
```

En el código anterior estás verificando que el caracter sea igual a `(` y en caso de que lo sea dentro del bloque de código vuelves a verificarlo pero ahora para ver si es igual a `[` lo cual será siempre falso porque si ya es igual a `(` entonces nunca será igual a `[`. Lo anterior lo puedes resumir así:

```
if (cadena.charAt(i)=='('){
    pila.add("(");
}
```

Ahora, para que no tengas `if`s `else if`s por montones puedes usar un `switch` para hacer la verificación:

```
private static boolean verificaParentesis(String cadena) {
    Stack<Character> pila = new Stack();

    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < cadena.length(); i++) {
            char c;
            switch (cadena.charAt(i)) {
                case '(':
                case '[':
                    pila.add(cadena.charAt(i));
                    break;
                case ')':
                    c = pila.pop();
                    if (c != '(') return false;
                    break;
                case ']':
                    c = pila.pop();
                    if (c != '[') return false;
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

    } catch (EmptyStackException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return pila.empty();
}
```

Los casos del switch serían los siguientes:

- Si el caracter es `(` o `[` lo mete a la pila.
- Si el caracter es `)` verifica que el tope de la pila sea `(` sino
  no está balanceada y devuelve `false` de una vez.
- Si el caracter es `]` verifica que el tope de la pila sea `[` sino
  no está balanceada y devuelve `false` de una vez.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el codigo maestro!!!! aun soy muy novato en esto

Y si ahora que has puesto los if tienes razon que nunca se cumpliran pues si en la iterarcion [i]=='(';
es imposible que el siguiente if se cumpla [i]=='['; pues son diferentes letras en iteracion, estaba quemado con tanto if no he comprendo muy bien para que sirve la pila seguire estudiando el codigo que me has puesto con el switch que parece algo mas sencillo

Gracias por todo!!!!